# CALLBACK INTERFACE in between fragments

Tags: android

now am  getting nullpointerException when building  the callBack Interface in between fragments. Please suggest  solution to overcome this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: share your sample code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

Comment: if you don't show all the code you are ussing for the callback, I'm affraid that we can not help you..

Comment: @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {  mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) context;  } catch (ClassCastException e) {throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");  } }

Comment: Actually , am new to callback , have no exact idea how to use

Comment: @SarathVK this is not the way to ask a question. Put your code, formatted, in main ask, not in comments. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you have any idea, please share with me about callback